# Is Barnes wearing an NVA belt buckle?

Tags: platoon

In the last few minutes of [Platoon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091763) (1986), Sergeant [Barnes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091763/characters/nm0000297) is wearing a belt buckle with a red star, which, I assume, is a trophy captured from a slain [North Vietnamese Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Army_of_Vietnam) (NVA) soldier. Is my assumption correct?  Has [Oliver Stone](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000231) ever commented on this?

I have watched the documentaries [A Tour of the Inferno](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368363) (2001) and [Brothers in Arms](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6111980) (2018) but, unfortunately, neither contained comments on belt buckles. I could not find anything related to belt buckles on what is alleged to be the movie's [script](https://archive.org/details/PlatoonScreenplayByOliverStone).

Answer (score 13):

In a word, yes. The belts were especially prized by veterans as it would allow them to modify their uniforms, distinguishing them from "fresh meat".

> Chris recognized the language but not the vocabulary. He stared in
> embarrassment at the nearly white leather of the men's jungle boots.
> Several pairs were held together by OD tape. Their uniforms were
> bleached by sun and sweat to lime white; modified, torn, ripped and
> patched beyond anything Chris had ever seen in Army uniform
> regulations. **A few of the men sported dull metallic belt buckles
> inscribed with a star,** and one individual was loaded down with a
> cracked Yamaha guitar and a weapon that Chris recognized as a Chinese
> Communist SKS carbine.
>
> <sub><sup>[Platoon: A Novel by Dale A. Dye](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9065329-platoon)</sup></sub>

Barnes has ready access to these sorts of grim souvenirs from their earlier encounter with a professional outfit.

> **Bunny had just stripped a bloody NVA belt off a gook killed by
> someone's Claymore.** He was fondling the prized souvenir and critically
> measuring the mangled corpse with his pale eyes.
>
> "That ain't no NVA, man. That's a chink, Rhah. Look at the size of
> that cocksucker. He's six and a half feet tall. Look at his gear, man.
> That shit's as good as ours."

Answer (score 5):

Is the belt a North Vietnamese Army soldier piece of clothing? According to the results of a search about this era and militaria clothing, many websites show the belt/buckle on the video as being a NVA belt, many similar models seem to be existing, including VC. Your assumption seems correct.

This is also mentioned in the article [Barnes' NVA Belt Buckle](https://whatculture.com/film/10-insanely-accurate-war-film-details?page=2):

> The star is an identifying mark of the North Vietnamese Army, better known as the NVA. Barnes' garment is likely a trophy taken from a fallen foe - a costuming choice perfectly in keeping with his ruthless character and a grisly real-life practice of armed conflict.

[Dale Dye](https://www.google.com/search?q=Technical+advisor+Dale+Dye+about+platoon) was the technical advisor, and his work suffers very little mistakes or complaints. I would definately give him credit for being right on this piece of equipment. I've searched his novel (Platoon - ISBN 10: 1121560644  ISBN 13: 9781121560642) and found this exceprt, the only one about equipment mentionning the belt.

[image]

---

Has Oliver Stone (or other crew member or producer) talked about it or commented? Didn't find any proof yet.

---

Belt buckles from the Vietnam War era:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sources for the pictures are [here](https://www.ima-usa.com/products/original-u-s-vietnam-war-north-vietnamese-army-nva-waist-belt-with-steel-buckle-2?variant=40273052958789) and [here](https://enemymilitaria.com/product-category/field-gear/belts-and-buckles/)